# Upper and Lower Sums for Negative Functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

The textbook I'm using to study integral calculus usually assumes for it's proofs that the function takes on only positive values. The author says that if we divide the x-axis into intervals, and pick the point in each interval for which the value of the function at that point is a minimum at the interval, then we can approximate the area under the curve using inscribed rectangles. Specifically, the author says, this would be the lower sum. The upper sum is achieved by picking the point at each interval for which the value at that point is the maximum of the interval. I was thinking: wouldn't this be the opposite for negative functions. Because the upper sum would be achieved by taking the minimum at each interval, at the lower by taking the maximum at each interval.

If I were to prove the same theorem for negative functions as well, is this the only difference that it makes?

Or is this not the case? Because if the upper sum is always the greater *numerically*, and the lower sum is always the less *numerically*. And if "negative area" is a thing, then the lower sum would still be the one that is formed by taking the minimum at each point, and the upper by taking the maximum. So I am confused with the exact definitions right now and would enjoy guidance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding what minimum and maximum are for negative values; these are not measured in terms of distance from zero, but simply in terms of the $x\le y$ relation.

These are all true:
$$
\min \{-1,-2,-3\} = -3
\qquad
\max \{-1,-2,-3\} = -1
$$
This is because $-3 \le x$ for every $x$ in that set, and because $-1 \ge x$ for every $x$ in that set.

We do not change the lower/upper sum definition for functions with potentially negative values as a result. Minimums, maximums, upper sums, and lower sums are all about being greater or lesser numerically.

Comment: No, I know that. I specifically wrote the question with that in mind. If we take the minimum at each interval for a negative function (the minimum at each interval is then the point at which the value is the greatest negative number) we will get the upper sum. While if we do the same for a positive function, we will get the lower sum.

Comment: No, that is not the case. In defining a lower sum,
$$
L(P,f) = \sum m_i \Delta x_i
$$
$m_i$ is simply defined by
$$
m_i = \min_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x_i)
$$
(up to your indexing scheme). The same is true of the upper sum, with a maximum. So ultimately this all ties back to the notion of minimum and maximum.

Comment: Ohh, I see where I misunderstood. So is the lower sum simply the one that is *numerically* less? Because then the lower sum is more negative than the upper sum (in case of a negative function), and hence less than it. See, I thought that "lower sum" meant the sum of *inscribed* rectangles in either case. In the case that the function is negative we are then circumscribing the rectangles to find the lower sum. So that caused the confusion, I believe. Would you confirm that that was so?

Comment: "So is the lower sum simply the one that is numerically less?" -- It is not defined that way, strictly speaking, but it is true. (That is, one can prove that the lower sum is always less than the upper sum.)

Comment: "See, I thought that "lower sum" meant the sum of inscribed rectangles in either case." -- This would only make sense for positive functions. If you've seen integrals before, there is a notion of a "signed" area, where we account for negatives, in precisely this way. For functions that aren't always positive, yes, it is the numerically lesser value for the lower sum.

Comment: " In the case that the function is negative we are then circumscribing the rectangles to find the lower sum." -- Circumscription has nothing to do with this process.